# How to add(increment) integer value like we do in other languages using ++(increment) operator in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add to integer `value + 1` , but I get 'no implicit conversion of Integer into Array'

Here is my code:

```
@user_id = User.limit(1).order('created_at desc').pluck(:user_id).map(&:to_i)
@user_id = @user_id + 1
```

Comment: Why not just do `User.order(created_at: :desc).first.user_id + 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'no implicit conversion of Integer into Array'

It's because `.pluck()` and `.map()` return an array.

- @user_id + 1 => is trying to add an array(@user_id) and an integer(1).
- Since 1 is an integer which should be cast to an array to get added to an array and **ruby doesn't want to do it implicitly**.
- Hence the error.

> Why not this?

`User.limit(1).order('created_at desc')` will return last active record. If `created_at` is not tempered you can achieve the same simply by

```
@user_id = User.last.user_id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`.pluck` and `.map` both returns an array type, so you're trying to do a numeric addition to array type, so you can do

```
@user_id = @user_id.first + 1
```

You can call `+` on array but it needs to be between two array types, e.g.

```
[1,2] + [3,4] => [1,2,3,4]
```

Hope this helps.